# Is <script>{' //pixel '}</script> correct in adding plugins to React <head>?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to know the correct way of embedding a `<script>` into my **ReactJS** and **GatsbyJS** application? This is an example of the code I want added to my `head`.

```
<script>(function(d,a){function c(){var b=d.createElement("script");b.async=!0;b.type="text/javascript";b.src=a._settings.messengerUrl;b.crossOrigin="anonymous";var c=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c)}window.kayako=a;a.readyQueue=[];a.newEmbedCode=!0;a.ready=function(b){a.readyQueue.push(b)};a._settings={apiUrl:"https://example.kayako.com/api/v1",messengerUrl:"https://example.kayakocdn.com/messenger",realtimeUrl:"wss://kre.kayako.net/socket"};window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent("onload",c):window.addEventListener("load",c,!1)})(document,window.kayako||{});</script>
```

I got it to work by wrapping the script in `<script>{' //pixel '}</script>` within `<helmet>` of my `index.js` - is this the correct way of doing things? I feel that it's too simple and wonder if I will expect issue later, for example should I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: Yes, use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even with `react-helmet`?

Comment: Yep, check out [how Gatsby plugins implement this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/src/gatsby-ssr.js#L13).

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated.